# PHP upload script where connection is secure

Tags: php, apache, security

I'm looking for a way to create a php upload script to my server where the connection is secure. The site would be only up for a a few minutes, so I'm not that worried, about getting junk files. However, I am worried about interception during the upload. Does anyone have any scripts that would handle that?

All the posts I find talk about how to secure the server against malicious uploads, which is different from what I need.... protection against malicious interception.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what ssl is for...

Comment: just run the script under https.

Comment: So lets get this straight. You want an anonymous person to give you software for a secure transaction. Perhaps I could supply it- but would it be secure?

Comment: Simple: Use SSL. Problem solved.

Comment: You could also only allow the server to be accessed by a known IP.  That would reduce the chance of interception.

Comment: Can someone provide some guidance how to make it use a ssl connection?

Comment: @dethtron5000 nope.  If the person who is uploading traffic is being intercepted, ACL on the server will do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SSL for encryption so it would automatically prevent from eavesdropping effect.

Have a Look on this [Stackoverflow Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318907/how-can-i-protect-a-php-image-upload-script-from-exploits)