# Testing Nginx+PHP5-fmp security

Tags: php, nginx

I would like to know if there is a toolset, project or something, that tries the most common bugs/exploits of Nginx + PHP5-fpm config, to test my server.

I am mostly scared about the ability to execute PHP code in user uploads directory (that is public, example: `http://somesite.com/uploads/aaa.gif`).

Comment: `software tools commonly used by programmers;`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318907/how-can-i-protect-a-php-image-upload-script-from-exploits